# mod_wsgi LoadModule for Python3 is ignored

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, python, mod-wsgi, flask

Trying to configure apache with mod_wsgi and Python3

mod_wsgi config

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /etc/httpd/mod_wsgi/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Flask App config

```
 WSGIScriptAlias /test /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/flask_app.wsgi
 <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
        # set permissions as per apache2.conf file
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
 LogLevel warn
 CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
```

I installed mod_wsgi for Python3 using pip3 install mod_wsgi4.6.7.tar.gz.

mod_wsgi.so for Python2.7 works but for Python3.6.6 it ignores the loadmodule directive.

The above is to setup a Flask application that will handle restapi.

Comment: Did you try to load both wsgi modules at the same time? Only one can be loaded as wsgi_module.

Comment: I removed the older module from the system using yum remove, just had one and it worked.